# Installing Windows 7 through Bootcamp for Mid-2011 iMac - How to Delete Hidden Partitions

Tags: terminal, windows, bootcamp, imac, partition

So I was hoping to install Windows 7 onto my computer. It's an old Mid-2011 iMac that I wanted to use for gaming and other programs. The problem however was that after deleting a second partition, it still said it couldn't run, implying I had more than one partition. I looked this up and came across the terminal command of `diskutil list` .

[image: The results after typing diskutil list into terminal.]

So apparently I have "hidden" partitions, which I want to get rid of so I can install  Windows 7 through boot camp...but...I need to know: what is the safest possible way of doing this? Becuase if I'm using Terminal the LAST thing I wanna do is delete important code for my Mac, lest I reinstall my OS from scratch.

Comment: You need to remove either `disk0s3` or `disk0s4`. Most likely `disk0s4`. The command for doing this would be the following. `diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s4`

Comment: Note that Windows 7, 8 and 8.1 are not supported by Microsoft anymore. You should consider upgrading to Windows 10 or install Windows 10 instead of Windows 7. A direct install of Windows 10 probably would not be supported by the Boot Camp Assistant. In other words, you probably would have to manually install Windows 10.